# Custom control toolbar need to invoke methods on my VM. How to do that?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, mvvm, custom-controls

Here is my question. I have `UserControl` that wraps group of buttons and it looks like this: (I show 2 buttons to illustrate what it is)

```
<Button Content="Cancel"
        IsEnabled="{Binding State, Converter={StaticResource CancelEnabledConverter}}">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
            <ei:CallMethodAction MethodName="Cancel" TargetObject="{Binding}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Button>

<Button Content="Delete" 
        IsEnabled="{Binding State, Converter={StaticResource DeleteEnabledConverter}}">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
            <ei:CallMethodAction MethodName="Delete" TargetObject="{Binding}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Button>
```

Now, when I place this `UserControl` on my view - I go by convention and create `Cancel` and `Delete` methods on my VM. So, view's XAML looks clean.

I want to create custom control that will have same functionality. Inside control I will have to handle `onClick` events for buttons and would like to call methods on VM just like it works now. What my code going to look like? I guess I need to access `DataContext` programmatically and call method by name somehow. I envision using control like so:

```
<myToolBar Mode="SaveExitDelete" />
```

So, this will be nice and short. But `myToolBar` will show 3 buttons and those buttons will call 3 methods(named by convention) on DataContext.

Any pointers?

**EDIT**

Main question is to how programmaticaly BIND command or method to button. I understand how commanding works, I'm using PRISM and it's got built-in DelegateCommand that I can use. I don't know how to create binding programmaticaly when I know Method name or command name.

Here is how I can see it working:

`var button = new DitatToolbarButton();
button.Caption = "Cancel &\nExit";
button.Icon = new BitmapImage(new Uri("img_btn_cancel.png", UriKind.Relative));
button.Command = Binding("CancelCommand");`

Obviously 3rd line is wrong but this is what I want. I want to be able to hardcode string that will contain name of command that I will expect VM to have.

Comment: Is there a reason you've decided not to use Commands for this?

Comment: How do I call commands by name from custom control? I don't use commands right now since not all controls support them and I wanted consistent syntax. I do use commands when I need paramter but I still use Interaction Triggers from Blend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, this sort of thing would be done with Commands. In the case of a Button control, which already has the "Command" DependencyProperty, it's as simple as this:

```
<Button Command="{Binding DoItCommand}">Do it</Button>
```

and in your view-model class:

```
private ICommand DoItCommand
{
    get
    {
        return new DelegateCommand(param => DoIt(param), param => CanDoIt(param));
    }
}
```

where DoIt() and CanDoIt() are methods in your view-model and DelegateCommand is defined something like this:

```
public class DelegateCommand : ICommand
{
    public DelegateCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        // ...
```

There's a decent example of this [here](http://relentlessdevelopment.wordpress.com/2010/03/30/simplified-mvvm-commanding-with-delegatecommand/). On a custom control, you can declare the Command DependencyProperty yourself. And on a framework control that does not have a Command DependencyProperty, you can use an [attached property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx).

Comment: Eben, I understand this part, I was wondering how to programmaticaly bind to Command. Or, better yet, to Method.

Comment: Okay, so apparently you are simply asking how to create the binding programmatically. I'm not even sure this will work without setting the Source upfront, but it seems you would need to do something like this: 

    Binding binding = new Binding("CancelCommand");
    button.SetBinding(ButtonBase.CommandProperty, binding);

Ultimately, it's a code-smell in my opinion to create a binding in code. Not necessarily wrong, but there's probably a better way to do what you're doing.